# Email is already registered

Tags: support

I tried to update my email address today, but I always get the message

```
Email is already registered
```

when I save the profile. I changed my *openid* login a couple of weeks ago, could that cause problems now?

I also removed a gmail address from my logins today. Any hints?

Comment: Try contacting the team: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/other

Comment: Done. Thanks @ShaWizDowArd